# How to sanitize an object obtained with belongs_to in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, ruby-on-rails-3, belongs-to

I have two classes: User and Message. Below are the definitions:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :receiver, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key  => 'receiver'
  belongs_to  :sender, :class_name   => 'User', :foreign_key  => 'sender'
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :incoming_messages, :class_name => 'Message', :foreign_key => 'receiver'
  has_many :outgoing_messages, :class_name => 'Message', :foreign_key => 'sender'
end
```

When I get messages in the controller, I also get the User objects in

```
@message.receiver
```

and

```
@message.sender
```

These objects contain some user information (passwords etc) that I would like to remove before passing it to the view (a json object in my case). What is the best way of doing this?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are manually rendering the objects in the view, no need to sanitize - the response will only contain the elements you expose.

If you are using AJAX and to_json, there are several ways of removing the information. You can use a select in the initial Model.find to ensure that the senstive information is not actually returned from the query. See [Active Record Querying - selecting specific fields](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields) for more.

The alternative is to override the JSON rendering itself to only display the required fields, using:

```
to_json(:only => [ :column, :column ])
```